# How do you ensure an XMLHttpRequest() has received its full response before continuing?

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, async-await, xmlhttprequest

I'm looping `XMLHttpRequests` and for each response I'm pushing it to an array.

I use async/await to try to ensure that I only return my array of responses once all of the responses are recieved.

For some reason, with no error, this method is not working and I am not getting the full response array.

```js
// looping requests in function

const getFetched = async () => {
  return Promise.all(
    await getURLArray().then(async (requestURLArray) => {
      const fetchedData = [];

      await requestURLArray.map((value, index) => {
        const requestUrl = value;
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        Http.open("GET", requestUrl);
        Http.responseType = "json";
        Http.send();

        Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
          if (Http.response === null) return;      
          fetchedData.push(Http.response);
        };       
      });

      return fetchedData;
    })
  );
};

// calling function to make requests

const fetchedData = await getFetched.then((fetched) => {
  // from the above, if I log fetched it has the correct data in it
  // but this is because of the console updating it after the promise
  // so if I log fetched.length it is 0 - meaning it hasnt properly fetched the data yet
})
```

What can I do to ensure that the `Http` request is completely finished before returning the array of responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `fetch` instead, as it works with `Promise`s.

```js
return Promise.all(
    (await getURLArray()).map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
);
```

Comment: Marked as correct - I think the other guy actually wrote his answer with ChatGPT since it got deleted and he answered within about 10 seconds of me posting the question.